# Aggregating Repeating Labels in Excel Sheet into Proper Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have an excel file with two columns: the first contains a repeating sequence of 14 labels, while the second contains the text values associated with those labels. What I'd like to do is aggregate this so that it forms a proper table, where there is just one set of labels and every set of values gets its own column. Preferably, to deal with column limits, I'd like to transpose this so that each label has its own column. Is there an easy way to do this without VBA or will I need to bust out the code?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a pivot table.

Comment: @Kyle Sorry about that, the reason I can't use a pivot table is that the values are largely text values. Updated question.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your worksheet data, or perhaps clarify the nature of your aggregation? What sort of text data is in the 2nd column, and how do you want to aggregate it?